# How can I make an accordion expand upwards in Divi theme?

Tags: divi, divi-theme

I'm trying to expand an accordion in upward direction in Divi theme, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I have tried in various ways but without finding the solution to my problem.
Any suggestions?

This site has an accordion like the one i need: https://hauserandolive.com/

Thanks, Pato

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.